# Python 'ndarray' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, netcdf4

I am trying to store some data in MYSQL database using python script, but i got the following error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters;
Python 'ndarray' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

Actually I am extracting variables from netCDF file and trying to store them in MYSQL db. my code is

```
import sys
import collections
import os
import netCDF4
import calendar
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

table = 'rob-tabl'
con = mysql.connector.connect(user='rob', password='xxxx',
                                  database=roby)
cursor = con.cursor()


smeData = """
        CREATE TABLE rob-tabl (
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `time.val` double,
        `time.microsec` double,
        `temp.degrees` double,
        `humid.calc` double,
        `pressure.calc` double;"""
```

these are my fields/ columns names in mMYSQL database. I am trying to insert netCDF4 data into MYSQL

```
smeData = "INSERT INTO `" + table + "` "
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

data_array = []
for item in totfiles.items(): # loop on different netCDF files in a                      directory , but at the moment I had only one file
    nc = Dataset('filename', 'r')
    data1 = nc.variables['time'][:]
    data2 = nc.variables['microsec'][:]
    data3 = nc.variables['temperature'][:]
    data4 = nc.variables['humidity'][:]
    data5 = nc.variables['pressure'][:]
    data = data1 + data2 + data3 + data4 + data5
    data_array.append(data)
    print 'data_array: ', data_array
    cursor.execute(smeData, data_array)
```

or if i try to combine all variable like this

```
data_array = []
for item in totfiles.items():
    nc = Dataset('filename', 'r')
    data1 = nc.variables['time'][:]
    data2 = nc.variables['microsec'][:]
    data3 = nc.variables['temperature'][:]
    data4 = nc.variables['humidity'][:]
    data5 = nc.variables['pressure'][:]
    data = ([(data1).tolist(), (data2).tolist(), data3.tolist(), data4.tolist(), data5.tolist()])
    data_array.append(data)
    print type(data)
    for v in data:
        cursor.executemany(smeData, (v,))
```

when I print netCDF variables data, e.g time variable, it looks like
this

```
nc.variables['time'][:] # netCDF variable
```

i got this

```
[1302614127 1302614137 1302614147 ..., 1302614627 1302614647 1302614657]
```

and microseconds looks like

```
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
```

and the data_array looks like

```
data_array=  [[1302614127 1302614137 1302614147 ..., 1302614627 1302614647
 1302614657], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [21, 22,34,34....,67,55], [12.2, 12.54, 12.55....,45.54,45.48], [0,0,0...,0,0,00]]
```

but if I print

```
for v in data:
    print v
```

then i got 1st list only within list and not the other lists which I guess is my main issue.

```
[1302614127 1302614137 1302614147 ..., 1302614627 1302614647 1302614657]
```

and if i try to do cursor.executemany(smeData, (v,)) command , it gives me this error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in 
the SQL statement
```

my MYSQL insert syntax is 
 my MYSQL syntax is

```
"INSERT INTO `rob-tabl` (`time.val`,`time.microsec`,`temp.degrees`,
`humid.calc`,`pressure.calc`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
```

In my case it is numpy.float32. I created 5 columns in MYSQL and I had to store data from netCDF into db.
I am new to programming and I am learning. if someone help me or give some hint how can I deal with such a error. I shall be very thankful.
thanx a lot.

Comment: Often people encode an array as a string (e.g. with `pickle`, `np.save`), and save that to the database as `BLOB`.  But it looks like you are trying to save arrays as numeric field columns.  Have you tried `arr.tolist()` to convert a 1d array into a simple list?

Comment: Give a sample of the MYSQL fields definitions.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you very much for the help, I will add a sample of MYSQL fields and will come back soon.  yes i am trying to write 5 fields to database. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: @hpaulj hpaulj I added columns names of MYSQL database and also the data of variables when I print them. I try tolist method and I hope it can solve my problem but I think I am not using it correctly that why I got that new error.

Comment: My answer, especially the last data build fits your edits.  Make a list of lists, and insert with the (?,?...) format and use `executemany`.

Comment: @hpaulj i think it will work if i make a list of lists. let me try and I will come back soon to update.

Comment: @hpaulj I accept your answer because tolist() works perfectly fine for me. thanx a lot for your help and time. have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with `sqlite3` rather than MYSQL, but I think the sql will be similar

```
In [709]: import sqlite3
In [711]: conn=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
```

define a simple 3 field table:

```
In [714]: conn.execute('create table test (x, y, z)')
Out[714]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xa943cb20>
```

define a numpy array, 4 'rows', 3 'columns'

```
In [716]: data = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

`tolist` converts it to a list of lists of numbers:

```
In [735]: data.tolist()
Out[735]: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

I can insert it into the table with:

```
In [719]: conn.executemany('insert into test values (?,?,?)',data.tolist())
Out[719]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xa93dfae0>
```

And test the insert with:

```
In [720]: for row in conn.execute('select x,y,z from test'):
     ...:     print(row)
     ...:     
(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
(9, 10, 11)
```

So it has written each sublist of `data.tolist()` as a record in the table.

I'm guessing that you want to write 5 fields to database, corresponding to the `data1`, `data2` etc from each `Dataset`.

To get more help I'd suggest including the `create` command, test with just one `Dataset`, and show (or sumarize) the `dataarray` that you are trying to insert.

Another way of creating a compatible list of lists is:

```
In [736]: data = [np.arange(3).tolist(),np.arange(10,13).tolist(),np.arange(20,23).tolist()]
In [737]: data
Out[737]: [[0, 1, 2], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22]]
In [738]: conn.executemany('insert into test values (?,?,?)',data)
Out[738]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xa93df320>
In [739]: for row in conn.execute('select x,y,z from test'):
     ...:     print(row)
     ...:     
....
(0, 1, 2)
(10, 11, 12)
(20, 21, 22)
```

---

In [mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters;Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213013/python-list-cannot-be-converted-to-a-mysql-type) you are trying to save a list of 5 lists, each sublist 2000 items long.  Lets expand my example.

I have (3,10) `data` array

```
In [881]: data
Out[881]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
       [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
       [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]])
```

`data.tolist()` would make a 3 element list, with 10 element sublists.

```
In [884]: conn.executemany('insert into test values (?,?,?)',data.tolist())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-884-6788d19a96ab> in <module>()
----> 1 conn.executemany('insert into test values (?,?,?)',data.tolist())

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 10 supplied.
```

`sqlite3` is giving a different error than your MYSQL, but I think the underlying issue is the same - that of trying to write a 10 element list or tuple to a 3 field record.

But if I first transpose the array, I get a list of 10 sublists

```
In [885]: conn.executemany('insert into test values (?,?,?)',data.T.tolist())
Out[885]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xa6c850a0>
In [886]: for row in conn.execute('select x,y,z from test'):
     ...:     print(row)
....
(0, 10, 100)
(1, 11, 101)
(2, 12, 102)
(3, 13, 103)
(4, 14, 104)
(5, 15, 105)
(6, 16, 106)
(7, 17, 107)
(8, 18, 108)
(9, 19, 109)
```

the transpose list is:

```
In [887]: data.T.tolist()
Out[887]: 
[[0, 10, 100],
 [1, 11, 101],
 ...
 [9, 19, 109]]
```

A well known Python idiom for 'transposing' lists uses `zip`.  It actually produces a list of tuples, which might be a good thing.

```
In [888]: list(zip(*data))
Out[888]: 
[(0, 10, 100),
 (1, 11, 101),
 (2, 12, 102),
 ....
 (8, 18, 108),
 (9, 19, 109)]
```

A list of tuples is easier to format:

```
for row in data.T.tolist():
    print('%s,%s,%s'%tuple(row))
for row in zip(*data):
    print('%s,%s,%s'%row)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help. it works perfectly fine and according to my need.

Comment: Sorry but I had one little question. tolist() works fine , but when I have 5 lists withoin list then I got problem which state "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
" and I updated my question. if you can give me a little clue, I will really thankful and it will save my day. or I should post this as a new question?.

Comment: I don't understand that until data everything is fine but when I try to store by using cursor.execute, then I got the problem. something is going wrong with MYSQL command.  if I try to insert single variable , it goes well but multiple variables storing is given me this error.

Comment: What is the `SQL` statement?  In my example, there is one `?` for each field and element in the inner lists.  You may need to review SQL syntax.

Comment: my MYSQL syntax is "INSERT INTO `rob-tabl` (`time.val`,`time.microsec`,`temp.degrees`,`humid.calc`,`pressure.calc`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

Comment: my syntax looks similiar, I mean I had five %s for 5 variables. I think my syntax is taking all 5 list and try to insert for the first variable only.

Comment: I update my question and include MYSQL syntax. if you can give any hint. it would be extremely great.

Comment: is this the correct way to add list? ..............    data = ([(data1).tolist(), (data2).tolist(), data3.tolist(), data4.tolist(), data5.tolist()])

Comment: I figure out the problem but no idea how to solve. Actually it only prints 1st list within list and does not take into consideration the other lists . I can update my question. if you had time , you can look into my question. thanx a lot.

Comment: I added an example of saving a (3,10) array into my 3 field table.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will give it a try and if its works fine, I will come back here to update you. Once again thanx for your time and help.

Comment: thanx a lot for your guidance and solution. list(zip(*data)) works fine and I had solved my problem from your valuable tip. I will delete my other question because from your solution in this question solve my problem. once again thank you very much. you save my whole day. .Have a nice day. .