# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters;Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, netcdf4

I am trying to store some data in MYSQL database using python script, but i got the following error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; 
Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

Actually I am extracting variables from netCDF file and trying to store them in MYSQL db. my code is

```
import sys
import collections
import os
import netCDF4
import calendar
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

table = 'rob-tabl'
con = mysql.connector.connect(user='rob', password='xxxx',
                                  database=roby)
cursor = con.cursor()


smeData = """
        CREATE TABLE rob-tabl (
        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `time.val` double,
        `time.microsec` double,
        `temp.degrees` double,
        `humid.calc` double,
        `pressure.calc` double;"""
```

these are my fields/ columns names in mMYSQL database. I am trying to insert netCDF4 data into MYSQL

```
smeData = "INSERT INTO `" + table + "` "
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
data_array = []
for item in totfiles.items(): # loop on different netCDF files in a
                               directory , but at the moment I had only one file
    nc = Dataset('filename', 'r')
    data1 = nc.variables['time'][:]
    data2 = nc.variables['microsec'][:]
    data3 = nc.variables['temperature'][:]
    data4 = nc.variables['humidity'][:]
    data5 = nc.variables['pressure'][:] 
    data = ([(data1).tolist(), (data2).tolist(), data3.tolist(), data4.tolist(), data5.tolist()])
    data_array.append(data)
    print type(data)
    for v in data_array:
        cursor.executemany(smeData, (v,))
```

when I print netCDF variables data, e.g time variable, it looks like
this

```
nc.variables['time'][:] # netCDF variable
```

so the data1 looks like this

```
[1302614127 1302614137 1302614147 ............., 1302614627 1302614647 1302614657]
```

and microseconds which is data2 looks like

```
 [0 0 0..................., 0 0 0]
```

and the data_array looks like this because it consists of five different lists.

```
data_array=  ([1302614127 1302614137 1302614147 ..., 1302614627 1302614647
 1302614657], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [21, 22,34,34....,67,55], [12.2, 12.54, 12.55....,45.54,45.48], [0,0,0...,0,0,00])
```

and if i try to do cursor.executemany(smeData, (v,)) command , it gives me this error

```
Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

my MYSQL insert syntax is

```
"INSERT INTO `rob-tabl` (`time.val`,`time.microsec`,`temp.degrees`,
`humid.calc`,`pressure.calc`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
```

I created 5 columns in MYSQL and I had to store data from netCDF into db.
if someone help me or give some hint how can I deal with such a error. It would be great. thanks

Comment: @Ike Walker , thanx for the editing.

Comment: What's the length of each sublist?  With that `insert` command it should be 5, one value for each `%s`.

Comment: @hpaulj I mention and show sublist print in my question. there are five list and I use 5 %s accordingly. .but if i want to see len. e.g print len(data1), it results in 2000 because I had 2000 values in every list.

Answer (score 0):

Although I never used it from what I saw:

```
smeData = "INSERT INTO `rob-tabl` (`time.val`,`time.microsec`,`temp.degrees`, `humid.calc`,`pressure.calc`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.executemany(smeData, data_array)
```

whithout the for loop.

Comment: from what i see data_array must be [(),(),()] type. A list with tuples values. You have a list with list values. Maybe this is the problem. Convert the inside lists to tuples and try it again (with the smeData i wrote or like it). And by the way the data_array must include the values this means 5 values per tuple. If it has more this will not work

Comment: Can you show me an example.  and I mention in my question that actually every sublist consist of almost 2000 values. how can I convert them to tuple and then a group of 5.  thanx a lot for the help. .

Comment: Its working with lists inside list. I tried with pymysql which is similar to mysql. So at data = ([(data1).tolist(), (data2).tolist(), data3.tolist(), data4.tolist(), data5.tolist()]) the data1.tolist() and others are single values or what? They have to be single values because later you data_array.append(data). Btw you can make them tuples if you set data as: data = (((data1).tolist(), (data2).tolist(), data3.tolist(), data4.tolist(), data5.tolist()))

Comment: I solve my problem by using zip and taking transpose. like list(zip(*data)). . but thanx a lot for the help and guidance.